# Weird screen glitch in Ubuntu (when black dominates)

Tags: video, screen, asus, video-player

When I create, say, a fully black image and then zoom into it -- as far black starts dominating the screen -- it starts weirdly flickering.

For instance, doing this

[image: Screen glitch]

I see something like (and it keeps flickering):

[image]

**What could that be?**

*gpu_burn* (video memory test) gives no errors.

And, as you can see, the recorded video does not contain any glitches.

Specs: [ASUS G750JW](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G750JW/specifications/) Laptop, GTX765M video card.

Comment: It's a 'video artifact', which is a fancy way of saying something's happening which should not be happening.  There are six different G750J laptop models according to https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/; on the serial number sticker, what's the letter which follows J in the model number?  If you're not using the 418.88 driver https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/149219 try it.

Comment: @K7AAY It's G750JW4019H and my driver info is [here](https://pastebin.com/JrH9PVfu).

Comment: You're not using the 418.88 driver http://geforce.com/drivers/results/149219 so, after making and verifying a backup, please try it

Comment: @K7AAY How did you determine that? Why not 430?

Comment: Newest search result I got on the GTX765M at https://www.geforce.com/drivers yesterday. Got newer? By all means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a hardware problem, or a video driver problem.

**To help eliminate a hardware problem...**

Boot with `nomodeset`, which will eliminate the video drivers as a concern. Screen resolution will be off, but retest using your black screen test, and see if the same problem occurs. If the problem still occurs, then you have a hardware problem.

- Boot to the GRUB menu
- Hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- Use the arrow keys and find the string "quiet splash"
- Change it to "quiet splash nomodeset"
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting

This is a temporary setting and will only last until the next boot.

**Update your Nvidia video driver...**

You have version 390.116, and 418.88 is the current version for your GTX765M video card. Get the newer version at https://www.geforce.com/drivers.

Note: Have good backups before installing the newer driver.

**Check your BIOS version...**

In the `terminal` app, type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and note the version number. Version 210 is the current version, and can be downloaded from https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G750JW/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Note: Check your model # to verify that this is the correct ASUS web page.

Note: Have good backups before installing the newer BIOS.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, please, tell me about booting with nomodeset.

Comment: @RubiShnol please see the update in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem is that I get these artifacts only sometimes and usually right after suspend. They go away after some time. If I boot with nomodeset, I probably won't notice any difference.

Comment: @RubiShnol but if you run with nomodeset for a while, it'll tell you if you have a hardware or software problem. The way I'm setting it is only for the current boot though. Go ahead and update your video driver and BIOS. Keep me posted, ok?

Comment: Already did that. But how can I make sure that nomodeset is enabled? Because I didn't notice anything. And, yes, there are no artifacts.

Comment: @RubiShnol  If nomodeset is enabled, you should see limited resolution choices in the `Displays` setting panel, and your normal screen resolution may be different than your normal setting. Nomodeset is only used for testing. If you've run it long enough, then the newer video driver should probably fix it.

Comment: Sure! Ok, so, I got just one resolution option and this is my default one. So, I can't really judge ...

Comment: @RubiShnol Did your BIOS need the update?

Comment: It turns out I get these weird artifacts only after playing Far Cry 2 on Steam. After a restart, they go away. Strange.

Comment: @RubiShnol but it also failed on your black screen test, yes? Have you installed the newer video driver and BIOS yet?

Comment: I finally found what the problem is. It is the monitor cable or whatever it is there that connects the display to the base. Any thoughts on this? Is such an issue reparable or is it a sign for laptop change?

Comment: @RubiShnol I thought so. Are you talking about the internal laptop video cable, or something external to the laptop. If we're talking internal, does opening/closing the lid make the problem occur.

Comment: That's exactly the closing/opening. In fact, even just touching it in a certain way or moving.

Comment: Without moving the lid, trying pressing your thumb onto the bottom of the face of the display screen and see if you can create the problem. Are you technically inclined?

Comment: I'd not want to go DIY if that's what you mean. No, touching the bottom of the screen does not cause these problems. It's moving the lid.

Comment: The video display cable is intermittently defective, or it has a bad connection at the motherboard, or at the display itself. From your description, it sounds like one of the first two. Take it to a technician to evaluate/repair.

Comment: That's exactly what I'll do. Will report here tomorrow

Comment: So, I talked to a technician. Unfortunately, we couldn't locate the issue precisely. We tried to reconstruct the artifacts, but, as always, nothing happened at the technician. He asked me to test with an external monitor, what I'm doing now and it's all fine again. This really puzzles me. Because yesterday I definitely saw the artifacts as moved the lid.

Comment: @RubiShnol the tech needs to open the laptop, and physically check the video cable, and check that it's properly seated at both ends... and most importantly, needs to examine the cable where it passes through the laptop lid hinges.

Comment: Well, this alone would cost 80 EUR. I have time till Friday to study the issue better. I think I'll take your advice and try to communicate it to him. He suggested me to rule out the video card before the thing gets disassembled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105098/discussion-between-heynnema-and-rubi-shnol).